# Permission about a app that will interact with other apps

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I want to develop an app that will interact with other apps.With interacting i mean that when an app like facebook or a browser is open my app will run in the same time.
I want to know which permission should i add to let the app interact with others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot interact with other apps without root - Except if you use an interface provided by the app itself.

You can display something over other apps using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```